The styles are not displaying after the build in React with MUI
I've built my React project, but the styles are not displaying. None of my styles are showing up, only MUI components, their styles, and plain HTML. More precisely, the styles appear only if I go into the browser's Source, into the stylesheet file (yes, the stylesheet is listed in the browser) and write something there. It doesn't matter what, even if I just add a space. So, as I've already mentioned, the styles appear and everything works, but only under this condition. JavaScript works immediately without any additional manipulation in the source code.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I use Nginx to serve static files.
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

As the header states, I use MUI for the interface. I write styles in SCSS. I have a separate SCSS file for each React component, which I import using "...". In index.jsx, there's main.scss, font imports, and style reset. Here's my index:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';

import { ThemeProvider } from './assets/styles/theme/ThemeContext';
import '@fontsource/open-sans';
import './assets/styles/main.scss';
import 'normalize.css';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

if (rootElement) {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  );
} else {
  console.error('Root element not found');
}

reportWebVitals();

Another interesting point is that when I make changes in the source in my stylesheet file, a request is made to Nginx, and the browser requests the font (I removed the fonts and built without them. As a result, it just stopped requesting them).
The first thing I did was tell the browser not to cache.
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
    expires off;
}

Then I removed styles, fonts, changed the link format, deleted the link, updated dependencies, and so on.

Did you manage to find a solution for that? I am facing the exact same issue

Issue in mime types
